# How to choose upper cutoff frequency of an amplifier?

Tags: mosfet

In Albert Malvino's Electronic Principle book, he gave an example how to compute the upper frequency of  a MOSFET amplifier:
[image]

The book chose 48MHz as the upper cutoff frequency which seems wrong to me since the gate bypass cutoff frequency is lower(only 2.2MHz). The book also shows the bode plot showing that 48Mhz is the upper cutoff:
[image]
The midpoint voltage gain is 22.2dB so the bode plot correctly shows the upper cutoff frequency which is at 19.2dB(minus 3dB of midpoint voltage gain 22.2dB).

I thought that in choosing the upper cutoff frequency, the lower frequency is the correct one since that is the time it will start to roll minus 20dB/decade and when 48MHz comes it will then start to roll minus 40db/decade.Why choose the higher frequency as the upper cutoff frequency?

Comment: Think. What's the ***mechanism*** causing the claimed LP roll-off corner? You have all the pieces. But what ***exactly*** is the mechanism by which the gain reduces? Can you express it in words? What is going on, exactly?

Comment: It rolls down because the capacitor' reactance is now smaller(high freqeuncy) causing the output voltage to short to ground instead of being passed wholly to the load resistor, right?

Comment: No. That's not the reason. Or, at least, it's not the reason ***I*** had in mind.

Comment: I can only think of the virtual bypass capacitors shorting the signal to ground..I thought it should start to roll off at 2.2MHz since the input voltage is now being shorted to ground so only a fraction of it will be passed to the gate of MOSFET and thus the output voltage to start to lower and lower .

Comment: What I see is an output impedance that is \$R_D\,\mid\mid\,R_L\$, driving a DS load and also a *drain-towards-gate* capacitance that provides a source of negative feedback, which then (because it ***is*** negative) tends to reduce the input signal and thereby reduce the effective gain. I'm not sure of *their* calculations. I haven't thought about them and I don't use discrete MOSFETs nearly as much as I do discrete BJTs. But I can see where it comes from, in broad strokes. I assume they got their math right.

Comment: Thats the Miller capacitance, right? That's the virtual cap I'm saying. The input capacitance is very big that's why the cutoff freqeuncy is lower and more and more input signal to decrease thus output voltage to decrease. That's why I thought it should have been the 2.2MHz and not 48MHz

Comment: I don't have any doubt that the input is filtered where you think it is. But the question is also, how is the output itself limited? I'll leave that question for the real experts here, though.

Comment: Yes, the upper cutoff frequency is 2.2MHz, not 48Mhz.